# Convert QString to LPTSTR, only first character shows up

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, lptstr

I'm trying to convert the following `QString` :

```
QString nom, prenom, promo;
...
QString modelName = nom + "_" + prenom + "_" promo;
```

into a `LPTSTR`.

So far, I've used this:

```
LPTSTR mm = (LPTSTR) modelName.utf16();
```

But the `LPTSTR` returned contains only the first char of the `QString`. I'v tried a lot of methods, including going through a `char *`, but nothing worked.

**What should I do to get the full QString into the LPTSTR**?

Comment: Where is the code that proves you only get the 1. character ? And are you certain you're using the unicode win32 API ?

Comment: mm is written afterwards in a file that I open with another software. In this one, I can only see one letter.
But when I directly type the name in, LPTSTR mm = "TEST CODE"; it works just well.

Comment: How can we be sure that you didn't do anything wrong when you wrote the string to that file ? However, if LPTSTR mm = "TEST CODE" works, your arn't compiling with the UNICODE #define, and your LPTSTR is 8 bit characters, not 16 bit characters. Perhaps you need modelName.toLocal8Bit(), or modelName.toUtf8() instead.

Comment: I'm not the one writing the file. I'm calling a function in a library given with the software, and I don't know what's happening in it ater I give it the variable. But once again, if I directly fill mm in the code, like mm = "TEST", it works fine.
And no, I'm not sure I'm using the unicode Win32 API. How could I check that?

Comment: You should mind, that `modelName.utf16()` became invalid, so you may not store this pointer anywhere.

Comment: Next question: what is LPTSTR in your build configuration? It is LPSTR or LPWSTR?

Comment: That's the question actually; read the comments in the answer, it's related to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `LPTSTR mm = "TEST CODE"` works well, then in your project the `sizeof(TCHAR)==1`. The little endian memory layout of an ascii UTF16-encoded string is:

```
xx 00 xx 00 xx 00 xx 00 ...
```

That's why, with a single-byte `TCHAR`, your UTF-16 string is interpreted as a single character string. The first zero byte terminates it.

There are two solutions to this problem:

1. To use UTF-16 `TCHAR`, you need to define `UNICODE` for the entire project. You can either add

   ```
   DEFINES += UNICODE
   ```

   to your qmake project file, or add

   ```
   #define UNICODE
   ```

   as the first line of your code, in every header and .cpp file.
2. If you really wish to use the locally encoded, byte-wide `TCHAR`, then you need to obtain them as follows:

   ```
   QString modelName = ...;
   QByteArray modelNameLocal = modelName.toLocal8Bit();
   LPTSTR mm = (LPTSTR)modelNameLocal.data();
   ```

   The `mm` value will remain valid as long as `modelNameLocal` is in scope. You need to be careful to ensure that as long as `mm` is used, the underlying byte array must exist as well.

Comment: @Rems you should understand the difference between pointer and array. Because there are a lot of potential errors. Kuba Ober describes everything well. +1

Comment: @DmitrySazonov I'm actually quite a beginner in C; I've worked on Java or Web (php) mostly and I'm not really used to all those subtlilities. Thanks for helping by the way!